# Why The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(new View.OnKeyListener(){}, int, String[]) is undefined

Tags: android

Why The constructor ArrayAdapter(new View.OnKeyListener(){}, int, String[]) is undefined in following my coding. This coding is for fetching data from SQLite when typing word count is more than 3 character. But, it's displaying the following error.

> The constructor ArrayAdapter(new View.OnKeyListener(){}, int,
>   String[]) is undefined

```
ed1 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.searchWord);
ed1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
{
    Integer count = 0;
    String typeWord = "";
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {                   
        if (KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()) {
            if (keyCode != 67) {
                count++;
                char c = (char)event.getUnicodeChar();
                typeWord = typeWord + c;
            }
            else {
                count--;
            }
            if (count > 2 && typeWord != "") {                                                                              
                countries = getAutosuggestWord(typeWord);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.autosuggest, countries);
                ed1.setAdapter(adapter);                            
            }
        }                       
        return false;                       
    }              
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to qualify the use of `this` when you want to refer to the enclosing class of an inner class. In your code, if the enclosing class is your Activity subclass (let's say it's called MyActivity), then you would write:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this,
   R.layout.autosuggest,
   countries);
```

Comment: Wow.. It's great. You save my life.

Answer (score 4):

The constructor is not defined because `this` is a reference to `View.OnKeyListener`. Use `YourOuterClass.this` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no outerclass. It's in onCreate.

Comment: @ppshein - there is an outer class: your activity class. dtmilano's answer (like mine) is correct because you are creating an anonymous inner class with `new View.OnKeyListener() {...}`. Inside the `{...}`, `this` refers to the anonymous inner class, not your activity class.

Comment: That's what I meant, YourActivity.this.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `this` points to the current instance of `View.OnKeyListener` class. The constructor of ArrayAdapter takes **current context** as first parameter which is your outer class name i.e., View (say MyActivity).

You should use `MyActivity.this` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ridiculously late but I usually use `getActivity()` in this circumstance. So it would look like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.autosuggest, countries);
ed1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup here